# Groovy alternative of Java8's .map() stream operation

Tags: java, groovy

What is Groovy's alternative for Java 8's `.map()`?

Example:

```
List<String> codes = events
    .stream()
    .map(event -> event.getCode())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I was trying to do

```
events.each { it; return it.getCode() }.collect() as String[]
```

but I am getting `List` of `String`s, but `toString()` representation instead of code

Comment: `events.collect { it.code }` or `events*.code` as a syntactic sugar.

Comment: Just events.*{it.code}

Comment: `each` is more suited for sideeffects (it returs the list that goes in (no returns or breaks possible)

Comment: your code is not correct for several reasons: you do each which is meant to do some operation on each element but does not yield a value out of that, the events are passed as they were at the beginning to the next method, collect, where you did nothing in the closure: the collect in groovy does the same as the map in java, but you need a condition on what to collect: it.code (what to map to in java parlance). After that there is no need of anything equivalent to java collect which is converting the stream to a list, cause in  groovy you already have a list

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Consider the `collect` method as illustrated below:

```
class Event {
    def code
    def name
}

def events = []
events << new Event(code: '001', name: 'a')
events << new Event(code: '002', name: 'b')

def codes = events.collect { it.code }

assert ['001','002'] == codes
```

Note that an equivalent Groovy idiom is the [spread-dot operator](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-spread-dot-operator.html):

```
def codes = events*.code
```